# restify example TODO server not sending responses

Tags: response, restify

I'm new at this and developing my first API server. I wanted to see an example of a POST request so I installed restify 3.0.3 and tried to run the TODO server example. I see the requests logged at the server but no response is sent. I'm using the sample curl requests provided and the server is running on Cloud9. Curl is running on windows 7.

For example, I've tried:

- curl -isS http://test-atk9.c9.io | json
- curl -isS http://test-atk9.c9.io/todo -X POST -d name=demo -d
  task="buy milk"

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the same behavior when using PostMan to exercise the example.

Setting the PostMan Header `Accept:text/plain` or `Accept:application/json` worked for me.

BTW: if you set `Accept:text/html`, you should receive a helpful response:

```
{
  "code": "NotAcceptableError",
  "message": "Server accepts: application/todo,application/json,text/plain,application/octet-stream,application/javascript"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did it. Thanks very much.